# TypedQuery throws null while Query works fine

Tags: java, hibernate, junit, mockito

I have such a query:

```
final String namedQueryName = Report.QUERY_NAME_FIND_BY_ENTITY;
final Query query = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery(namedQueryName);
query.setParameter("pEntityName", entityName);
```

which works fine, however, as a good practice I would like to use TypedQuery, so I changed it to:

```
final String namedQueryName = Report.QUERY_NAME_FIND_BY_ENTITY;
final TypedQuery<Report> query = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery(namedQueryName, Report.class);
query.setParameter("pEntityName", entityName);
```

now, when I run junit tests with mockito getEntityManager()... returns null.

```
@Mock
private static TypedQuery<Report> query;

@Test
public void findByEntity_empty() {
    when(entityManager.createNamedQuery(Report.QUERY_NAME_FIND_BY_ENTITY)).thenReturn(query);
    when(query.setParameter("pEntityName", "NOTHING")).thenReturn(query);
    List<Report> reportsDB = new ArrayList<>();
    when(query.getResultList()).thenReturn(reportsDB);
    assertEmpty(reportDAO.findByEntity("NOTHING"));
}
```

Why `getEntityManager().createNamedQuery(namedQueryName, Report.class);` returns null instead of creating query?

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Mocking the entitymanager doesn't make much sense. But anyway. You're using createNamedQuery(String, Class), but you're mocking createNamedQuery(String). So your code never calls the method you mocked.

Comment: easy fix! Thanks. Why it doesn't make sense? If I do not want to DB calls at this point is it still a bad approach?

Comment: Typically, you would put the code that uses the EM to execute requests in a DAO service, and you would mock the DAO to test the service layer, that uses DAOs. The code of the DAOs consisting only in executing requests using the EM, you would test that the requests they do actually work and retur  the correct values, thus not mocking the EM.